# Accessing mysql db using python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, solaris

I have recently started learning python.
We do access our mysql db using shell scripts a lot.
I wish to use python to learn as well as implement some new things in our project.
We are working on Solaris OS. The Python version that is installed on our servers is 2.6.4.

I see that by default sqlite3 modules are already present.
Can I use the same for accessing my mysql db?
I cannot install any new module in our servers, so I cannot install a mysqldb module.

Is there any tweak that I can do with using only the standard modules of python?

Is there any alternative way that I can access mysql db with the mysqldb module?

Comment: You're stuck with installing module...

Comment: You can use virtualenv to install modules for your personal use without root access, but if this is for others to use they will either have to create a virtualenv or someone with root will have to install the module.